# PowerShell equivalent of “dirname $0” from bash

Tags: powershell, filepath, idioms, dirname

I've used `dirname "$0"` which is an idiom to determine the path of the running script in bash, e.g.:

```bash
pushd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

```bash
data_dir="$(dirname "$0")/data/"
```

What's PowerShell equivalent of the above idiom?

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PowerShell version 3.0, the execution context provides 2 script-scoped automatic variables:

- `$PSCommandPath` - the file system path to the executing script, eg. `C:\path\to\script.ps1`
- `$PSScriptRoot` - the immediate parent folder of the script, eg. `C:\path\to`

So the equivalent of your last statement would be as follows in PowerShell:

```
$dataDir = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot data
```